# Grouping based on a category from Table

Tags: oracle

i have a specific scenario where the subtotals and totals would need to be shown based on a selection parameter .
So the table has players and their attributes as shown below .

[image]

The user can select any or combination of the TYPE fields .
Below is the query result needed when TYPEA and TYPED are selected.

[image]

Below is the query when TYPEB and TYPEC are selected.

[image]

The user can select 3 TYPE or 4 type fields for which subtotals and totals are needed.
Any assistance is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `rollup` or `grouping sets` in sqlplus with [break](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpug/BREAK.html#GUID-8C5811BC-01DF-4D95-A3A0-5C42C546534F):

```sql
break on TYPEA skip 1 on TYPEB skip 1 on TYPEC on TYPED;
with t(runs, run_percentage, name, typea, typeb, typec, typed) as (
select 50, 22.22222 , 'PLAYER1', 'BAT'  , 'RIGHT', 'OPENER'  , 'TALL'   from dual union all
select 45, 20       , 'PLAYER2', 'BAT'  , 'RIGHT', 'OPENER'  , 'TALL'   from dual union all
select 40, 17.77778 , 'PLAYER3', 'BAT'  , 'LEFT' , 'OPENER'  , 'TALL'   from dual union all
select 35, 15.55556 , 'PLAYER4', 'BAT'  , 'LEFT' , 'STRIKER' , 'SHORT'  from dual union all
select 30, 13.33333 , 'PLAYER5', 'BOWL' , 'RIGHT', 'OPENER'  , 'TALL'   from dual union all
select 25, 11.11111 , 'PLAYER6', 'BOWL' , 'RIGHT', 'STRIKER' , 'SHORT'  from dual
)
select
  typea, typeb, typec, typed
  ,sum(runs) runs
from t
group by rollup (typea, typeb, typec, typed);
```

Results:

```
TYPE TYPEB TYPEC   TYPED       RUNS
---- ----- ------- ----- ----------
BAT  LEFT  OPENER  TALL          40
                                 40
           STRIKER SHORT         35
                                 35
                                 75

     RIGHT OPENER  TALL          95
                                 95
                                 95

                                170


BOWL RIGHT OPENER  TALL          30
                                 30
           STRIKER SHORT         25
                                 25
                                 55

                                 55


                                225



16 rows selected.
```

[More examples of `rollup` and `grouping sets`](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/rollup-cube-grouping-functions-and-grouping-sets)